# Bootstrap script not working for the toggle menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

> I want my toggler menu to work but it does not i want to know why it does not work?I will like to also know want links that i need to remove and how to improve my website speed.I resize the broewser and find out that the website is not show the toggle menu icon but it is there but it will not open a new menu

```html
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v3.8.6">
    <title>Pipes and Wheels</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/examples/jumbotron/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Favicons -->
 
<link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.4/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="/docs/4.4/assets/img/favicons/browserconfig.xml">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#563d7c">


    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-white">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img style="height: 100px;" src="logo.png" alt=""></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: black;">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#jumbotron1" style="color: black;">Our goals <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where did you get that HTML code from? When I compare it to the [Bootstrap 5.2 Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/#navbarSupportedContent), it does not match. The `.container-fluid` is missing, toggles use `data-bs-toggle` and not `data-target`. Is it version 4 code?

Comment: You are using 2 different version of bootstrap

Answer (score 3):

After reviewing your HTML code, I can see that you're using two different versions of Bootstrap. You're using 4.4.1 for CSS and 5.0.2 for JS. I believe it should work if you first unified the versions, then based on the selected version check docs for proper HTML markup

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can follow these links for relevant docs for each version [Bootstrap 4.4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4), [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0)